# how do i get values from non mvc asp.net page to mvc asp.net page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get the values from non MVC asp.net page to MVC Controller and want to dispaly those values in a  view page,how can I do that?
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

hi You can use State Management to do that,

if you want to pass 2-3 values then you can use QueryString to do that or you can also use session to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by 
**Asp.Net to MVC Controller :** by Session
**MVC Controller to View :**  by ViewBag

**Asp.Net Code**

```
Session["value1"] = "someValue";
```

**MVC Contoller Code**

```
string temp = Convert.ToString(Session["value1"]);
ViewBag.value1 = temp;
```

**View Page Code**

```
@ViewBag.value1
```

Hope it may help you. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can post the form to MVC controller, and read the form 
var data = Request.Form["yourtagName"].
this will help all the values to be secured rather than passing in Querystring or storing in Session.